# check input length not more than 10

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to check my value length and make it only to 10 numers.What is my problem?

```
 function checkNumbers(input)
    {   
     if (document.getElementById("answer").value.length == 10)
        {
        input.value = input.value.replace(input.value, '');
        } 
    }

    <input type="text" maxlength="10" onkeyup="checkNumbers(isAllowedSymbol(this));checkNumbers(this); "placeholder="Enter data" name="answer" " > <br>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery - check length of input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702862/jquery-check-length-of-input-field)

Answer (score 3):

In your html your using `name` and in your js you are lookng for `id`

change `name='answer'` to `id='answer'`

Or alternatively in your JS try:

`document.getElementsByName('answer')[0].value==10`

Answer (score 0):

You should put both functions into one.
Here you go:

```js
function checkNumbers(input)
    {   
        var value = input.value;
        var rep = /[a-zA-Z]/;
        var rep2 = /[а-яА-Я]/;
        if (rep.test(value)) {
            value = value.replace(rep, '');
            input.value = value;
            if (rep2.test(value)) {
                value = value.replace(rep2, '');
                input.value = value;
            }
        }
     if (document.getElementById("answer").value.length == 10)
        {
        input.value = input.value.replace(input.value, '');
        } 
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="10" onkeyup="checkNumbers(this); "placeholder="Enter data" id="answer" >
```

Comment: function isAllowedSymbol(input)
 { 
  var value = input.value; 
  var rep = /[a-zA-Z]/;
  var rep2 = /[а-яА-Я]/;

  if (rep.test(value))
  { 
        value = value.replace(rep, ''); 
        input.value = value; 
    if (rep2.test(value))
    { 
    value = value.replace(rep2, ''); 
    input.value = value; 
    }
  } 
 }

Comment: This should be comment rather then answer.