# max length check not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Use 'getElementsByname' but it don't helps me. What I'm doing wrong? "isAllowedSymbol" function is working great but not "checkNumbers".

```
function checkNumbers(this) {
  var element = document.getElementsByname('answer')[0];
  if (element != null && element.value.length == 10) {
    element = element.replace(element, '');
  }
}

function isAllowedSymbol(input) {
  var value = input.value;
  var rep = /[a-zA-Z]/;
  var rep2 = /[а-яА-Я]/;

  if (rep.test(value)) {
    value = value.replace(rep, '');
    input.value = value;
    if (rep2.test(value)) {
      value = value.replace(rep2, '');
      input.value = value;
    }
  }
} 


<input type="text" maxlength="10" onkeyup="isAllowedSymbol(this);checkNumbers(this); " placeholder="Enter data" name="answer" "> <br>
```

I want to get by name,not id,what is my problem? Or may be I can get it only by "id"? Thank you.

Comment: `getElementsByName ` not `getElementsByname`

Comment: You can not accept `"this"` as argument...Make it `that`

Comment: @RayonDabre Since when can you use `that` in Javascript?

Comment: @C0dekid.php, _Since the day it was born_

Comment: @RayonDabre I don't know but `that` isn't declared??

Comment: @C0dekid.php it's just a variable name

Comment: Iknow, but it still confused me why he said use `that` instead of `this`. @Walk

Comment: @C0dekid.php, It can be almost anything.. You might have seen `that` is been used to refer `this`.. Just a choice of words mate!

Comment: @RayonDabre Haha, alright then! I tought it was a (_new_) function in JS :P

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check input length not more than 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689761/check-input-length-not-more-than-10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not accept `"this"` as argument reason being it is *Unexpected token this* Also typo @ `getElementsByname`. But as you are sending `this` from the `click-handler`, you do not need that. You can grab the element using any other argument name than `this`

```js
function checkNumbers(element) {
  if (element != null && element.value.length == 10) {
    element = element.replace(element, '');
  }
}

function isAllowedSymbol(input) {
  var value = input.value;
  var rep = /[a-zA-Z]/;
  var rep2 = /[а-яА-Я]/;

  if (rep.test(value)) {
    value = value.replace(rep, '');
    input.value = value;
    if (rep2.test(value)) {
      value = value.replace(rep2, '');
      input.value = value;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="10" onkeyup="isAllowedSymbol(this);checkNumbers(this); " placeholder="Enter data" name="answer">
```

Answer (score 0):

First you misspelled `getElementsByname`. Its proper name is `getElementsByName`. This function allows you to retrieve elements by their *element name*. If you want to select the `input` element whose `name` attribute is `answer`, then use:

```
var el = document.querySelector("input[name=answer]");
```