# Input max length checking

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with `"checkNumbers()"`. I'm trying to check if my input is not bigger than 10 numbers; `"isAllowedSymbol()"` is working great, but another don't. What is my problem?

```
 function isAllowedSymbol(input)
        { 
            var value = input.value; 
            var rep = /[a-zA-Z]/;
            var rep2 = /[а-яА-Я]/;

        if (rep.test(value))
        { 
        value = value.replace(rep, ''); 
        input.value = value; 
                if (rep2.test(value))
                { 
                value = value.replace(rep2, ''); 
                input.value = value; 
                }
        } 
    }
    var element = document.querySelector("input[name=answer]");


    function checkNumbers(element) {
      if (element != null && element.value.length > 10) {
        element = element.replace(element, '');
      }
    }

<input type="text" maxlength="10" name="answer" onkeyup="isAllowedSymbol(this);checkNumbers(this);" placeholder="Enter data" > <br>
```

Comment: Exactly what you want? This is coming , I need this...

Comment: typo here (placeholder="Enter data"  ") - should be (placeholder="Enter data")

Comment: You're trying to use the replace function (which is a member of the string object) on an HTML element that has a string (element). What you instead need to do is to use the replace method thusly: `element.value = element.value.replace(element.value, '');` If the length of the text in the field is more than 10, it (the field) will be cleared.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check input length not more than 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36689761/check-input-length-not-more-than-10)

Answer (score 0):

You have used `maxlength = 10` for input and thus you wont be able to add any new character to it and thus the condition that `element.value.length > 10` can never occur.

Use this:

```js
function isAllowedSymbol(input)
        { 
            var value = input.value; 
            var rep = /[a-zA-Z]/;
            var rep2 = /[а-яА-Я]/;

        if (rep.test(value))
        { 
        value = value.replace(rep, ''); 
        input.value = value; 
                if (rep2.test(value))
                { 
                value = value.replace(rep2, ''); 
                input.value = value; 
                }
        } 
    }
    var element = document.querySelector("input[name=answer]");


    function checkNumbers(element) {
      if (element != null && element.value.length > 10) {
        element.value = ''
      }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" maxlength="15" name="answer" onkeyup="isAllowedSymbol(this);checkNumbers(this);" placeholder="Enter data" > <br>
```

Comment: BTW its wrong logic there, if I write 11 length value then it erase all.. I guess it should erase last one added.. it should be `element.value = element.substring(0, 10);`

Comment: @Sac, Its not clear from the question whether the OP wants to clear complete value or the last entered value. I interpreted as the complete value and wrote the code. If he wants to clear the last character only then you are correct

Answer (score 0):

first what you want to do ?
if you want to do when your input more than 10 then input box will be clear then first edit in maxlength attribute of input box

```
<input type="text" maxlength="15" name="answer" onkeyup="isAllowedSymbol(this);checkNumbers(this); " placeholder="Enter data">
```