# Autofocus onto next input after maxlength has been met

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm looking to setup a standard DOB question where, once the user satisfies the `maxlength` requirement, it will automatically focus onto the next input (being the month field).

However, my current approach doesn't autofocus onto the next field?

```js
$(function() {

  $(".input").keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      console.log(this.maxLength);
      var $next = $(this).next('.input');
      if ($next.length)
        $(this).next('.input').focus();
      else
        $(this).blur();
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="question question--1">
  <input class="input" type="number" data-format="day" placeholder="DD" maxlength="2" />
</div>

<div class="question question--2">
  <input class="input" type="number" data-format="month" placeholder="MM" maxlength="2" />
</div>

<div class="question question--3">
  <input class="input" type="number" data-format="year" placeholder="YYYY" maxlength="4" />
</div>
```

I believe the issue might be because the next `.input` is in another parent element. I've tried tweaking it to the following:

`var $next = $(this).parent(".question").next('.input');`

But still the same results.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702862/jquery-check-length-of-input-field?

Comment: Here you'll find the answer with JQ and Vanilla JS also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595652/focus-next-input-once-reaching-maxlength-value

Comment: @Grumpy - Nope, I think it's the issue I am having is because my `inputs` are children of different parent `divs`. Existing questions on SO show all inputs under the same parent / level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for `$next = $(this).parent('div').next('div').find('.input');` length and focus on that  `.input` using `$next` not with `$(this).next('.input')`.

Example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".input").keyup(function() {
    if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
      var $next = $(this).parent('div').next('div').find('.input');
      if ($next.length) {
        $next.focus();
      } else {
        $(this).blur();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="question question--1">
  <input class="input" type="number" data-format="day" placeholder="DD" maxlength="2" />
</div>

<div class="question question--2">
  <input class="input" type="number" data-format="month" placeholder="MM" maxlength="2" />
</div>

<div class="question question--3">
  <input class="input" type="number" data-format="year" placeholder="YYYY" maxlength="4" />
</div>
```